# How to Cancel AlarmManager For Next Day

Tags: android, flutter, alarmmanager, alarm

2 Things I want to do with my alarm manager.

**1) Set alarm for daily.
2) Turn off alarm for Tommrow rest Alarm will on daily basis.**

As of now i can only set alarm for next 7 days but i want to set it for everyday till user didn't stop

manually stop i done but **struggling with these 2 issues**

Answer (score -2):

Here's a general outline of how you can approach this:

**Plugin:** android_alarm_manager_plus: ^latest_version

#### 1. Set Alarm for Daily:

In your app, use the `AndroidAlarmManager.periodic()` method to schedule a repeating alarm. For example:

```dart
await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(
  const Duration(days: 1), // Trigger every day
  alarmId,
  yourCallbackFunction, // Function to be called when alarm triggers
  startAt: DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 1)), // Start tomorrow
  exact: true, // Exact timing
  wakeup: true, // Allow the app to wake up the device
);
```

Ensure that `yourCallbackFunction` is a valid function that handles the alarm when it triggers.

#### 2. Turn Off Alarm for Tomorrow:

You'll need to provide a mechanism in your app for users to manually turn off the alarm for the next day. This could be a button or a setting in your app's UI. When the user interacts with this, you can cancel the previously scheduled alarm using `AndroidAlarmManager.cancel()`.

For example:

```dart
void cancelTomorrowAlarm() async {
  final int alarmId = 0;
  await AndroidAlarmManager.cancel(alarmId);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy